# Problems with preg_match and guzzle response

Tags: php, preg-match, guzzle

I 'am trying to preg_match a response recieved via guzzle. 
The problem is when i enter its content into my *everything_in_tags* function the peg_match function does not return any results.

The preg_match function works as aspected when i copy-paste the content of *var_dump($this->body)*  manually into the *everything_in_tags* function.

After the cast $this->body is a string object.

So now i'am wondering why it behaves that way and can somebody pls be so kind and tell me how i can resolve that issue.

Thx in advance.

**Code:**

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->dataRaw = (object) [];
  $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $this->res = $this->client->request('GET', 'https://www-   genesis.destatis.de/genesisWS/web/ExportService_2010?method=TabellenExport&kennung=kennung&passwort=password&namen=13321-0001&bereich=Alle&format=html&strukturinformation=false&komprimieren=true&transponieren=true&startjahr=2016&endjahr=2017&zeitscheiben=&regionalmerkmal=&regionalschluessel=&sachmerkmal=FAMSTD&sachschluessel=VERH&sachmerkmal2=&sachschluessel2=&sachmerkmal3=&sachschluessel3=&stand=&auftrag=false&sprache=de');

  $this->body = (string) $this->res->getBody()->getContents();
  $this->dom = new Dom;

  var_dump($this->body);


  $this->table = $this->everything_in_tags($this->body, 'table', false);

  $this->dom->loadStr($this->table , []);
  $this->html = $this->dom->outerHtml;
}

function everything_in_tags($string, $tagname, $inner) {
  $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
  preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
  return $matches[$inner ? 1 : 0];
}
```

**Guzzle-Response as String:**

```html
     200text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-11Bei mindestens einem Objekt sind Fehler      oder Warnungen aufgetreten.Information13321-000122Mindestens ein Parameter   enthält ungültige Werte. Er wurde angepasst, um den Service starten zu   können.: zeitscheibenWarnungAktualisierte
Daten28.09.201713321-000109:21:273888 3114 9999674 falseKNZPT13false falseERW0024falseErwerbstätige3Wfalsefalse falseERW1235falseVeränderungsrate zum Vormonat3Wfalsefalse falseERW1246falseVeränderungsrate zum     Vorjahresmonat3WfalsefalseInlands-/ Inländerkonzept0SKfalsefalseTemporär
false133211false falseDINSG2falseDeutschland insgesamt1RKfalsefalseErwerbstätigenrechnung in der VGR (national)0Efalsefalse8925 falseJAHR8false falseMONAT9falseMonate8ZKfalsefalseJahr0ZIfalsefalse falseWERTE17falseWerte0SKfalsefalse
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>GENESIS-Tabelle: Tempor&#228;r</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" summary="Die Tabelle Tempor&#228;r enth&#228;lt aktuelle Daten zur Statistik - Erwerbst&#228;tigenrechnung in der VGR (national) - mit Stand vom 28.09.2017 ">
    <caption>Erwerbst&#228;tige (inkl. Ver&#228;nderungsraten): Deutschland,<br />Monate, Inlands-/Inl&#228;nderkonzept, original/saisonbereinigte<br />Werte</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="Z4S1" colspan="8" align="left">Erwerbst&#228;tigenrechnung in der VGR (national)<br />Deutschland</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p></p>
     <div class="copyright">&#169; Statistisches Bundesamt (Destatis), 2017 &#160;&#124; Stand: 28.09.2017 / 09:21:27</div>
    </body>

   </html>Alle13321-0001false2017htmlfalseFAMSTDdetruefalse0
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you Guzzle-Response as String is really the output that you get, that is: what your browser will show you, when you call the page.

If that is correct, it is very very likely, that you don't understand what is returned from that URL. What is returned is some kind of xml containing xml, like this (or something remotely similar):

```
<soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body>[content]</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

however, the content that you're aiming for is most likely html-escaped, meaning: the `<table>` you see in your browser's output is actually `&lt;table&gt;` because the tags are content and not markup.

My advice is:

1. look at the actual source code in your browser (right-click: view source code or whatever), when you output your guzzle response, it should contain more output than you provided.
2. use an xml-parser (or a soap parser, or whatever parser, don't know if this is actually rpc) to find the content in the soap-envelope, then use an xml parser to parse that content.

this should be enough. However, I might be wrong.